# How do I get the List of Role and Number of users in them asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Please how do I get the list of roles, along with the number of users having the role? something like this [image]

I have tried this

var users = allusers.Where(x=>x.Roles.Select(role => role.Name).Contains("User")).count;

but this is just for one role. I need it for all the roles, and when a new role is added in the db, it should also add to the list.

Thanks

Comment: You need a `.GroupBy()` clause (on the `Name` field) and `.Sum()` the results of each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will be helpful to you.

```
var  result = ( from r in userManager.UserRoles 
                join u in userManager.Users on r.UserId equals u.Id
                group  new { r, u } by new { r.RoleId } into grp
                select new { name = grp.FirstOrDefault().r.Name, count=grp.Count()}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhilash, but I'm getting this error: The key selector type for the call to the 'GroupBy' method is not comparable in the underlying store provider. Thanks

Comment: In 'GroupBy' clause you have to give the correct field name for RoleName in your table. I just assumed it to be RoleName. You have to give your field name.

Comment: That is exactly what I did  var rolesUsers = userManager.Users.GroupBy(e => e.Roles)
               .Select(x => new UserRoleModel
               {
                   RoleName = x.Key,
                   NoOfUsers = x.Count()
               }).ToList();

Comment: So 'Roles' is the field in 'Users' table right. What is its datatype???

Comment: See the updated answer will be useful. Where 'Roles' should be the field in your user table.

Comment: My user table extends IdentityUser<Long, Login, UserRole, Claim>.

Comment: The code did not compile, when I did this:  var  result = ( from u in userManager.Users 
                group  new { u } by new { u.Roles } into grp
                select new { name = grp.Key , count =grp.Count() }).ToList();, it threw the same exception error. Thanks so far.

Comment: What is the error. Not { u. Roles } change it to { u.Roles.Name }

Comment: ICollection<userRole> does not contain a definition for Name and no extention method...sorry for late reply

Comment: What are the fields in your UserRole. What are the table actually you have .I don't understand.

Comment: It's the default fields that comes with asp.net identity UserRoles table (Just UserId and RoleId). Am assuming because it is the join table that's why.

Comment: please see the updated answer. I am not sure about field name. But this will works for you.

Comment: Wow!....Thanks Sooo Much. It finally works!...Thanks for your patience, I truly appreciate!. Have a nice day!.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is over a year old, but here is an update in ASP Core 2.2.
This code runs on a PageModel, and things are getting simpler :)

```
//Creation of class
public class RolesModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly ILogger<RolesModel> _logger;

    public RolesModel(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        ILogger<RolesModel> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

//(...)
//Now check in some class 

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    var RolesList = _roleManager.Roles.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

    foreach (var role in RolesList)
    {
        var RolesUserlist = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(role.Name);
        _logger.LogInformation($"Role {role.Name} has {RolesUserlist.Count} users");    
    }
}
```

Cheers